# How to add color preview to the Debug Sidebar's Variables window in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to add some meta data to a Variable when returned via DAP so VSCode shows a 'color preview' in the **Variables Window**? I know this is possible in the source, but are there any options for the variables while debugging?

[image]

Comment: What language is this? What type are the variables instances of?

Comment: @wjandrea thats the question, do I need to set them to a type to get VSCode to understand they are a colour? Its a custom language, with its own DAP implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, I don't know if this is possible. This is out of my wheelhouse, I was just hoping to get more details for any experts. I was thinking, if the language were like Python and the values (not variables) are strings then it wouldn't make sense to put a colour preview on them, but if they're like a `Colour` type, then it would. Anyway, again I don't know if this is possible.